# Four Seasons Total Landscaping

Tags: word-usage

Is the word "total" a usage of standard English? Or is it of regional English? The phrase "Four Seasons Total Landscaping" is the name of a company in Philadelphia.

> And now, when Siravo, 65, goes to work at the unassuming one-story redbrick industrial building on State Road, home to **Four Seasons Total Landscaping** for the last 20 years, “not a day goes by where there’s not a crowd outside.”

> Source:[The Philadelphia Inquirer](https://www.inquirer.com/news/philadelphia/trump-four-seasons-total-landscaping-what-happened-20201201.html)

Comment: It is a name of a place, or club, or baseball team. It can be anything creative. It has nothing to do with standard or non-standard usage.

Comment: And it can be meaningless?

Comment: Does New York have a meaning? Does Lakers have a meaning? Not all names necessary depict meaningful attributions.

Comment: _Total_ isn't meaningless, although, as David Siegel says, it doesn't add anything useful to this company's name. It is a perfectly standard English word. Have you looked it up in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat unusual but not incorrect construction in what seems to be a name devised for marketing effect.

"Total Landscaping" here is meant to suggest that this firm provides all possible t=landscaping services. It really has no substantive difference in meaning from "Four Seasons Landscaping", which would be a  much more usual form. But it is not uncommon to see a business labeled "Total X" to suggest that it totally or fully covers the field of X, whatever X might be. It is marketing buzz-speak, not good writing, but perhaps it is effective marketing.